# Looping through data using ODATA and SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Here is  simple example of a calculation view data.

```
Id      Supplier  Artikel   Type     Revenue
1          S1      ART1     1000       500            
2          S1      ART2     1200       600
3          S1      ART3     1300       600
4          S1      ART4     1400       600
```

I consume the calc view data using ODATA services. But, I would like to know whether there is a  way to loop through these rows and get the value of `TYPE` and `REVENUE` and set as  `LABEL` and `VALUE` respectively for a `TEXTFIELD` using `SAPUI5`. Is there a possibilty of such kind or any example code or any ideas please do share.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Row Repeater to show an iterated label value line see [Row Repeater with OData example](http://jsbin.com/qaqur/4/edit) else you could use a [Factory Function](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/BindingAggregations.html) with a aggregation binding